# Let Draggable behave like a Bottom Sheet

Tags: dart, flutter, draggable, bottom-sheet

I'm using a Draggable to create my own Bottom Sheet which contains some Textfields, but I'm facing some Problems:

- I want to restrict the draggable area so the sheet can't be moved higher then the height of the sheet (Like a normal bottom sheet)
- Textfields are blocked by the keyboard (Draggable doesnt move up when using Keyboard) [Here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHfRC.png)
- Sheet should be moved without showing draggable feedback

Is there a way to solve these problems or are there other ways to code this?

Here is my code nothing too special happens here:

```
    Positioned(
              top: position.dy,
              child: Draggable(
                child: bottomSheet,
                feedback: bottomSheetFeedback,
                axis: Axis.vertical,
                onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
```

`setState(() => position = offset);
                },
              ),
           ),`